# change the integer time to date format MM/DD/YY like datetime.fromtimestamp in python

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follow. In python with `datetime.fromtimestamp` we can change the integer time to date. I want to change the time column to `MM/DD/YY` in Mysql. Can you help me with that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1546322400) as date;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2018-12-31 22:00:00 |
+---------------------+

mysql> select date_format(from_unixtime(1546322400), '%m/%d/%Y') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 12/31/2018 |
+------------+
```

---

I forgot until the comment from nbk above that FROM_UNIXTIME() does support an optional second argument, so you can do this in one step:

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1546322400, '%m/%d/%Y') as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 12/31/2018 |
+------------+
```

Read about [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
and [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: very important to note "The value returned is expressed using the session time zone."

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime  is the simplest version

> ```
> SET @a = 1546322400
> ```

> ```
> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1546322400,  '%d/%m/%y')
> ```
>
> ```
> | FROM_UNIXTIME(1546322400,  '%d/%m/%y') |
> | :------------------------------------- |
> | 01/01/19                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c76c301cd79848a7ff391d4aab6fa0c5)*